# Order multiple columns in R

Tags: r

Sample data:

```
now <- data.frame(id=c(123,123,123,222,222,222,135,135,135),year=c(2002,2001,2003,2006,2007,2005,2001,2002,2003),freq=c(3,1,2,2,3,1,3,1,2))
```

Desired output:

```
wanted <- data.frame(id=c(123,123,123,222,222,222,135,135,135),year=c(2001,2002,2003,2005,2006,2007,2001,2002,2003),freq=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))
```

This solution works, but I'm getting memory error `(cannot assign 134kb...)`

```
ddply(now,.(id), transform, year=sort(year))
```

Please note I need speedwise efficient solution as I have dataframe of length 300K and 50 columns. Thanks.

Comment: `now[do.call('order', as.list(now[, -2])), ]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to sort it (which is called arrange in dplyr). `dplyr` is also faster than `plyr`.

```
wanted <- now %>% arrange(id, year) 
# or: wanted <- arrange(now, id, year)

> wanted
#   id year freq
#1 123 2001    1
#2 123 2002    3
#3 123 2003    2
#4 135 2001    3
#5 135 2002    1
#6 135 2003    2
#7 222 2005    1
#8 222 2006    2
#9 222 2007    3
```

You could do the same with base R:

```
wanted <- now[order(now$id, now$year),]
```

However, there is a diffrence in your `now` and `wanted` data.frame for id == 123 and year 2002 (in your now df, the freq is 2 while it is 3 in the wanted df). Based on your question, I assume this is a typo and that you did not actually want to change the `freq` values.

Answer (score 3):

You could use base R function here

```
now <- now[order(now$id, now$year), ]
```

or `data.table` for faster performance

```
library(data.table)
setDT(now)[order(id, year)]
```

or

```
now <- data.table(now, key = c("id", "year"))
```

or

```
setDT(now)
setkey(now, id, year)
```

Comment: I have tried with base R and order().Thanks for the lesson. (+1)